# Emacs continuously asking for input and not sure what is the cause

Tags: shell, async, compile

I have this function implemented to basically compile and run the cpp file I am writing. Some files needs input (cin) so running this function will not stop and would continuously showing this message:

```
emacs Enter a positive, odd integer (-1 to exit program): Only digits are allowed!
```

Not sure what is wrong:

```
  (defun run-it ()
    "Run it on the current file."
    (interactive)
    (save-all-buffer)
    (let ((file-name (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name)))
    (shell-command
     (format
        (concat "g++ -std=c++11 " file-name " -o " file-name ".o; "
                 "./" file-name ".o;")))
         ))
```

Comment: Although *perhaps* not the source of your problem, `format` does not do anything here, so maybe just remove it along with the opening/closing parentheses.

Comment: Surely not the problem, but you call the compiled *executable* `file.o`?

Comment: Probably `(save-all-buffer)` this is no official function. The rest works.